# Debian - Apache MySQL PDO issue but all logs are empty

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, debian

I'm trying to get a project set up and working but I have some issues with my PDO connection. No big deal, however, it doesn't matter what logs I'm trying to find - they are all empty.

- within the php file itself, I have `ini_set('error_log', '/tmp/php_error.php');`.
- within my `sites-enabled` config I have the error log defined under
  `${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error-domain.log`

both files are empty and don't track any errors.

I'm not a debian specialist by any means, what am I missing here? are there any other log directories to check? what could cause the system to not write any error messages.

Comment: How about the /var/log/apache2/error.log

Comment: mostly empty. only content of the log file is this: https://pastebin.com/raw/ptA0yWJf and it doesn't update when trying to connect to the db.

Comment: Is PDO configured to throw errors? https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php

Comment: thank you @ADyson! this helped to solve the issue. Would you answer the Post so I can mark you as correct answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure PDO is configured to throw errors, otherwise SQL queries may fail silently and you'll see nothing in your logs.

Add this to your code just after you create the connection (in this example `$conn` is a variable created from the PDO constructor (e.g. `$conn = new PDO(...` etc.).

```
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

Once this is configured, SQL errors resulting from a PDO command will be thrown as PHP exceptions. If PHP's normal error logging is configured correctly, these errors will then appear in your PHP error_log file.

Documentation: https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php

Comment: Thank you ADyson for the hint. With this I was able to get the error message (`Connection failed: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused`) displayed to the browser directly - my mysql wasn't listening to the IP or domain but only to `localhost`

Comment: No problem. (I'm a bit surprised though that you didn't see other warnings / errors in the log caused by subsequent attempts by the code to use a connection object which wasn't populated correctly. Depends how your code is written though, and whether you've got PHP configured to log warnings and notices, or just fatal errors.)